# How do I send data back to main page from xamarin.ios uitableview?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin.iOS. Please forgive me if my question is wrong. In my project, I have a button on an upload page. If the user clicks on that button, it goes to a UITableView page. The user can then select one row in that table. Then, it goes back to the upload page. I do not know how to get the selected table row value from the UITableView to the upload page. Please guide me. This is my code thus far:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableview view,NSIndexPath index)
{
new AlertView("Selected Row is",""+name[index.Row],null,"Ok",null);
NavigationCOntroller.PopViewController(true);
view.DeselectRow(index,true);
}
```

Comment: how to get name[index.Row] value in uploadviewcontroller  page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is declare the event inside UITableViewSource as something like `public event EventHandler<NSIndexPath> OnRowSelected` and call it in:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView view, NSIndexPath index)    {
    if(OnRowSelected != null)
        OnRowSelected(sender,index);
}
```

**Edit :**
To get the value from the previous page, you can try using Events to pass values.

In your ViewController containing the list, declare an event (eg.    `public event EventHandler<NSIndexPath> OnClose;`), then subscribe to the event from the controller you navigate from. If your navigation is via a Storyboard, do it in the PrepareForSegue method as follows:

```
if(segue.identifier =="YourSegueId"){
YourVc listVC = (YourVc)segue.DestinationViewController;
listVc.OnClose += listVc_OnClose;
}
void listVcOnClose(object sender, NSIndexPath arg){}
```

Now when you subscribed to event when selecting row store that index in field then when you call PopViewController the ViewWillDisappear will be called as well this is where you trigger your event:

```
ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    if(OnClose != null)
        OnClose(sender,TableViewSource.MyFieldThatStoresLastSelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: how to get this values in previous page? pls can u share code?